# Cannoto add QCheckBox to my window

Tags: java, qt, user-interface, qt4

For some reason this is giving me an error:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QCheckBox>

QWidget window;
QCheckBox botonera = new QCheckBox(window);
```

The error seems to be about the window (should be a pointer to `QWidget`), like `QWidget * window;`, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you put it as an answer so i can check it as Solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your code, window is null.  Or it has not been initialized....

So you need something like:

```
QWidget window = new QWidget();
QCheckBox botonera = new QCheckBox(window);
```